# Can't connect to my Amazon EC2 over SSH?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I've created an Amazon EC2 AMI from an existing server, ie I'm **not** using one of amazon's AMIs. I can launch it and I can see on the console output that it's started up, however I can't SSH to it, either as root or as a local user that was on the original server we copied.

I've tried with a few different keys, including some that i had made already. When I try to connect, it offers the SSH key but it doesn't except that and will ask me for a password. I tried the (root) password for that server. "PermitRootLogin yes" is in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config

I know I'm connecting to the SSH server, since it gives me the RSA fingerprint the first time. I've tried running this on US and EU.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my fault. I forgot to add 'root' to the `AllowGroups` in sshd config.