# How to get rid of firewall blockage to ssh to my ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, timeout, honeypot

I've made my ec2 instance on AWS and I worked on it at home like a charm and everything went fine (connection wise)

Today I went to the library and when I tried to ssh into my ec2 using PuTTy as I always do, the connect can't be made and I'm given the "network error:connection timed out" error message

I assume that's a firewall blocking my ssh access?Am I right -I even tried to telnet and it's the same

I have searched the internet and read these questions

[Can't connect to my Amazon EC2 over SSH?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52665/cant-connect-to-my-amazon-ec2-over-ssh?rq=1)

[Can't SSH Into EC2 Instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/302999/cant-ssh-into-ec2-instance?rq=1)

[ssh, telnet to AWS EC2 instance time out](https://serverfault.com/questions/617010/ssh-telnet-to-aws-ec2-instance-time-out?rq=1)

I need to know if my assumption is true and if yes how can I bypass it to ssh to my ec2 instance if my assumption is not ture tell me the real reason then

P.S: my security group rules allow IP address from everywhere 
     I changed my ssh port to 49153 as I used the 22 port for my honeypot I installed in my instance

Comment: The traffic is being blocked by the library's firewall. You will need to work with them to get the ports un-blocked.

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible whatever network your behind does not allow outbound connections to port 49153. One way to avoid this is to use the Java based client in your browser provided by Amazon.

Comment: I used the Mindterm tool but I got this error                           Error connecting to x.x.x.x, reason:
-> Connection timed out: no further information

Comment: The java applet does not bypass local firewall rules. The client is still connecting as usual.

Comment: @EEAA that's why then...do you have any solution?